# Can't write /etc/sudoers from Ubuntu live CD

Tags: live-cd, sudo

I messed up the /etc/sudoers file, now I need to restore it. Booted up the system with an Ubuntu Live CD, installed LVM and mounted the Volume. I'm root and I **can't write** to the `sudoers` file in my mounted hd.

I can't change the permission with chmod because system tell me it's a read-only file system.

What should I do?

Comment: by "messed up" you mean "I can't open the file and change it back" on your installation?

Comment: reboot, hold SHIFT, there you can edit the file, I think =), if necessary, I can give you my sudoers file so

Comment: I forced to save it with an error :(. I figure out how to do it, recovery mode, exit from read only file, drop on the root sheel and now I have the write permission :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figure out how to do it, recovery mode, exit from read only file, drop on the root sheel and now I have the write permission :D

Comment: Exit from what read only file and how?

Comment: I don't remember now but I think there is an entry on the menu when you boot the live cd with "exit from read only mode" or something similar

Comment: Hmm… I don't remember seeing that at any point. Maybe they removed it years ago but after you wrote your answer.

Comment: Ok maybe I get it. With "exit from read only file" I was meaning that you you have to remount the file system in write mode with `mount -o rw,remount /`

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you mounted your install Ubuntu system's root filesystem at `/mnt` on the transient live CD system, and that the partition is `/dev/sda1`.

Then remount it readwrite:

```
sudo mount -o rw,remount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

- If that fails, unmount the filesystem (with [`umount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/umount.8.html)) and [`fsck`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/fsck.8.html) it to find and repair any errors (see also [`e2fsck`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/e2fsck.8.html)).

Then you can edit its [`sudoers`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/sudoers.5.html) file like this:

```
sudo visudo -f /mnt/etc/sudoers
```

Actually, you can edit it as `root` using whatever mechanism you want. For example, to edit it in such a way as to allow you to introduce errors that break it and prevent `sudo` from working:

```
sudo -e /mnt/etc/sudoers
```

But [`visudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/visudo.8.html) is better because it won't save your changes to the file if they are syntactically wrong.

By using `visudo` when editing `/etc/sudoers` on your installed system (from the installed system), you avoid having to boot into recovery mode, or to a live CD, to fix it.

```
sudo visudo
```

If you do break your `sudoers` file, you can fix it without booting into recovery mode or rebooting, because there is another mechanism besides [`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sudo.8.html) for becoming `root`:

```
pkexec visudo
```

[`pkexec`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/pkexec.1.html) is the command-line frontend to [PolicyKit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/polkit.8.html). It is generally not present on server systems without a GUI, but it will be present on virtually any Ubuntu system with a GUI (and you do not actually need the GUI to be *working* to use it, though if there is a GUI it will give you an authentication window rather than authenticating in the terminal itself).