# sudo: /var/lib/sudo/navneet writable by non-owner (040777), should be mode 0700

Tags: permissions, sudo

This error occurs whenever I try to work with `sudo`. I changed the permissions of `/var/` folder to `777` and I think this causes the error. Please help me get back a functional `sudo` and `/var`.

Comment: try making it 555 ie. no write permission, only read and execute

Comment: Duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/234583/how-can-i-reset-the-permissions-of-var

Comment: @saji89 I'm not sure these should be considered duplicates. This is specifically asking about a problem with one file, is focused on getting `sudo` working again, and is primarily concerned with *how* to make the change; [that](http://askubuntu.com/questions/234583/how-can-i-reset-the-permissions-of-var) (while it's certainly relevant to the OP here) is about how to fix permissions for *all* the files in `/var` and doesn't concern itself much with *how* the changes will be made once it's been determined *what* they are.

Answer (score 5):

You have a really big problem, but ***not* really for [the reasons stated here](https://askubuntu.com/a/240254/22949).**

Changing the permissions on all of `/var` will make it likely you will not get them all back correctly, because *you will not know what permissions **every** file should have*. You may have problems later. Depending on the circumstances, your problems might be security-related.

Therefore, you may wish to consider reinstalling Ubuntu. Alternatively, you can [try to get the permissions from the files in another, similar, unbroken system](https://askubuntu.com/a/234591/22949). The permissions are usually the same. *Usually.* A more serious problem is that it's likely your system has some files in `/var` that are not present on the other one, so probably not *all* the permissions will be fixed.

**Performing administrative tasks on a desktop system without a working `sudo` is usually trivially easy, though.**

Changing the permissions back when you know what they should be is easy, and **rarely requires booting into recovery mode** or from a live CD. This is because, while it's not widely known, desktop versions of Ubuntu (and most other GNU/Linux operating systems these days) have *two* ways set up to perform administrative tasks:

- [`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sudo.8.html), which will not work because it requires the permissions in `/var` to be correct.
- [PolicyKit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/polkit.8.html), which tends to be more tolerant of wrong permissions and usually still works.

While we tend to think of `sudo` as the way you perform actions as `root` on Ubuntu, actually PolicyKit is the way most, though not all, graphical utilities become `root`. (It has been this way for some years now.)

Actually, running a graphical program manually with PolicyKit is sometimes a significant undertaking as graphical applications must have special configuration files for PolicyKit to be willing to run them. But *terminal applications* don't -- it's just as easy to run a text-based command with PolicyKit as with `sudo`.

To do it, type [`pkexec`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/pkexec.1.html) where you'd otherwise type `sudo`. (They don't take all the same command-line options, but the most common syntax for `sudo` is `sudo command`, and `pkexec` works perfectly in its place.)

So, because `sudo` is broken, you cannot run:

```
sudo chmod 0755 /mnt/var/lib/sudo
sudo chmod 0700 /mnt/var/lib/sudo/<username>
```

But you **can** run:

```
pkexec chmod 0755 /mnt/var/lib/sudo
pkexec chmod 0700 /mnt/var/lib/sudo/<username>
```

That's a good start, and it will probably make `sudo` work again. (It's not going to fix *all the other files in `/var`*, though.)

<sub>**Related (but, in most cases, not identical) situations where `pkexec` is helpful:**

‣ [How to modify an invalid /etc/sudoers file? It throws an error and it's not allowing me to edit again to fix it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-a-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-out-an-error-and-not-allowi)

‣ [accidently blocked access to sudoers.d whilst trying to change ushare config](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152038/accidently-blocked-access-to-sudoers-d-whilst-trying-to-change-ushare-config)

‣ ['sudo' not working after changing the permissions of '/usr' directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143554/sudo-not-working-after-changing-the-permissions-of-usr-directory)

‣ [How to fix sudo after "chmod -R 777 /usr/bin"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127446/how-to-fix-sudo-after-chmod-r-777-usr-bin)**,** [sudo error, is mode 0777, should be 0440](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50704/sudo-error-is-mode-0777-should-be-0440)**,**

           [How to repair "sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 0640, should be 0440?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189818/how-to-repair-sudo-etc-sudoers-is-mode-0640-should-be-0440)

‣ [Installing ZFS changed my sudoers file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152108/installing-zfs-changed-my-sudoers-file)

‣ [Password not working for sudo ("Authentication failure")](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152793/password-not-working-for-sudo-authentication-failure)

‣ [Why does nothing work after I randomly changed some file permissions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158346/why-does-nothing-work-after-i-randomly-changed-some-file-permissions)

‣ [changed /etc permission in oneiric (ubuntu11.10) by using "sudo chmod 665 /etc" cant use sudo now](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115358/changed-etc-permission-in-oneiric-ubuntu11-10-by-using-sudo-chmod-665-etc)

‣ [How do I run specific sudo commands without a password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password) (just if something goes wrong)

‣ [Can't write /etc/sudoers from Ubuntu live CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108515/cant-write-etc-sudoers-from-ubuntu-live-cd) (just if something goes wrong)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You have a really big problem in your hands.  First of all, in order to get you `sudo` working again, you will need to change the permissions of the `/var/lib/sudo` folder and the file `navneet` inside of it.

But, in order to do it, you will need root access.  If you happen to have changed the root password, then you will only need to `su -` and change the permissions as below:

```
$ chmod 0755 /var/lib/sudo
$ chmod 0700 /var/lib/sudo/navneet
```

And you are good to go.  But, if you haven't changed your root password, you will need to obtain root access by other means. On a standard Ubuntu install you can do this by booting into recovery mode. This is done by rebooting and hitting the shift key after the BIOS screen disappears. It is advisable to hit it repeatedly, but slowly. If you succeed the GRUB Menu will  come up and you can chose the second option (marked recovery mode). From the next menu you should chose root shell. This will bring you to a root prompt. On 12.04 you will need to make the hard drive writable to make any changes. The command for this is `mount -o,remount,rw /`. It make take several attempts to bring the GRUB menu up.

Alternatively you may use a boot CD.I suggest you to use the Gentoo minimal installation CD, as it is small in size and will get the job done, there are also several specialist recovery CD's available. A standard install CD will often  work if you choose to live boot rather than install.  Boot your computer through the CD, and mount your partition to `/mnt/` (`mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`), for example.  Then you may change the permissions like this:

```
chmod 0755 /mnt/var/lib/sudo
chmod 0700 /mnt/var/lib/sudo/navneet
```

It is best to use this to backup your data and then do get a fresh install. Since other applications may stop working because of wrong permissions, and there could be other consequences that compromise the security of your machine.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar error, but was still actually able to use sudo (It displayed the error message, and it did what I told it to do after that.), so I fixed it with:

```
sudo chmod -R 0700 /var/lib/sudo
```

(I was running Ubuntu 14.04)